# How to pass a parameter from code to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a aspx page where I have a gridview and inside this gridview i added a datalist, so for each row i want to have a datalist, Basically the row contains an Image and in the datalist I want to display certain details about the Picture, For example, a pic of a truck and in the datalist i want to display the price, year, etc... All this data is in a database table.

Table Inventory Design:

```
Image,
Make,
Model,
Price,
Year, 
ID--primary key
```

At this point I'm display the image in the gridview, but the datalist is showing all the rows that are in the table on every row of the grid What I want to to is only display the data that describes the image of the current row. For example, the first row should only display data in the datalist where ID = "15 and the second row where ID = "16" and so on.

In the SelectCommand for the SQLDataSource that fills the datalist, i'm trying to pass "WHERE ID = @ID" parameter and get it from the codebehind page so i can manipulate the data and only display the data that corresponds to the image and not all the data in each row over and over.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                 SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Make], [Model], [Year], [Price] FROM [Inventory] 
                 WHERE ID = @ID" OnLoad = "SqlDataSource1_Load" 
                 OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
                 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

THIS IS KIND OF WHAT I WANT, CODE BEHIND

```
 public partial class Inventory : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
     protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList DataList1;
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        }

     public void SqlDataSource1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("ID", this would be where my ID 
                   should = the id of the image);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you take a bit more care when you write questions in future, thanks

Comment: why don't use listview     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500643.aspx

Comment: I think I'm going to give it a try to the list view if I can format it like i want to, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking will result in a database trip for each grid-view row. The better solution would be to get all relevant data in a single trip and then bound the child data-list with the filtered items. For example, make data-base call to stored procedure (or a batch with two queries) that would return two tables - first with images and ids that you can bind to grid-view while the second table would contain other information for all ids from first table. Now you can bind the data list with a DataView that filters for the required id.

See this MSDN article for various examples on nesting data-bound controls - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478959.aspx

On different note, I am also not sure if the data-list information (make, model, price, year) has multiple values for a given id/image. If that's not the case then you don't need to use data-list at all but rather use a custom template using template field for the verticle layout that you want to achieve.

Comment: do you have an example i can look at? thanks for your response

Comment: @Edward, example for nesting? See the MSDN link sighted - check out section titled "Binding to Hierarchical Database data" - that describes the use of single DB trip and data-view for child control.